# Null exception @Service in a spring @RestController using constructor injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

This is my third personal spring-boot project, I am doing 99% same config than before so have no clue why I am getting this error on this one.

The project startup just well but once I do any petition on the unique @RestController I have, it immediately gets the null error. This end point receive an alpha 2 country code + city name + the desire ip address, if ip address is not provided it takes the client ip address which is used as param for the @Service I am getting null from. After that the controller should do many other actions before send the expected output to the client but it never reaches that point since the null exception on this @Service.

This is the petition I am trying on:

```
http://localhost:8080/apiv1/get-distance?country=af&city=Qalat&ip=150.135.184.38
```

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot invoke "me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.services.CurrentLocationService.getCurrentLocation(String)" because "this.currentLocationService" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.services.CurrentLocationService.getCurrentLocation(String)" because "this.currentLocationService" is null
    at me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.controllers.DistanceController.getDistance(DistanceController.java:53)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

This is my controller:

```
package me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

import me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.dtos.CityDto;
import me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.dtos.CountryDto;
import me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.entities.CityEntity;
import me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.entities.CountryEntity;
import me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.models.ApiCurrentLocationResponse;
import me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.models.Coordinate;
import me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.models.DistanceResponse;
import me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.repositories.ICitiesRepository;
import me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.repositories.ICountriesRepository;
import me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.services.CurrentLocationService;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RequestMapping("/apiv1")
@Validated
@RestController
public class DistanceController {

    private final CurrentLocationService currentLocationService;
    private final ICitiesRepository citiesRepository;
    private final ICountriesRepository countriesRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public DistanceController(CurrentLocationService currentLocationService, ICitiesRepository citiesRepository,
                              ICountriesRepository countryRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.currentLocationService = currentLocationService;
        this.citiesRepository = citiesRepository;
        this.countriesRepository = countryRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    @GetMapping("/get-distance")
    @ResponseBody
    private ResponseEntity<Object> getDistance(
            @RequestParam(required = true, name = "country") @Min(2) @Max(2) String country,
            @RequestParam(required = true, name = "city") String city,
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "ip") @Min(7) @Max(15) String ip,
            HttpServletRequest request) {

        ApiCurrentLocationResponse currentLocation;
        if (ip == null || ip.isEmpty()) {
            String requestIP = request.getRemoteAddr();
            System.out.println(requestIP);
            try {
                currentLocation = currentLocationService.getCurrentLocation(requestIP);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            try {
                currentLocation = currentLocationService.getCurrentLocation(ip);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        CountryEntity countryEntity = countriesRepository.getById(country);
        CityEntity cityEntity = citiesRepository.getByNameAndCode(city, country);

        CountryDto countryDto = convertToCountryDto(countryEntity);
        CityDto cityDto = convertToCityDto(cityEntity);

        Coordinate currentLocationCoordinate = new Coordinate(currentLocation);
        Coordinate destinationCoordinate = new Coordinate(cityDto);

        Double distance = currentLocationCoordinate.distanceBetweenUsKm(destinationCoordinate);

        DistanceResponse response = new DistanceResponse(countryDto, cityDto, distance);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response);
    }

    private CityDto convertToCityDto(CityEntity cityEntity) {
        return modelMapper.map(cityEntity, CityDto.class);
    }

    private CountryDto convertToCountryDto(CountryEntity countryEntity) {
        return modelMapper.map(countryEntity, CountryDto.class);
    }
}
```

This is the "null" @Service:

```
package me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.services;

import me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.models.ApiCurrentLocationResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@Service
public class CurrentLocationService {

    private final WebClient.Builder webClient;

    private final String key = "fakekey347834834892923fake";

    public CurrentLocationService(WebClient.Builder webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    public ApiCurrentLocationResponse getCurrentLocation(String requestIP) {

        String url = "https://api.fakeapi.app/json/";
        return webClient.baseUrl(url).build().get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path(requestIP)
                        .queryParam("apikey", key)
                        .build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(ApiCurrentLocationResponse.class)
                .block();
    }
}
```

Thanks your really appreciate help. If any other information is required please let me know. Thank you!
----------------Edit--------------------
shivam's comment gave me the idea of tag with the @Autowired my injections so I did it and I am not getting the null exception in the @Service anymore, it is in the ICountriesRepository instead which is just the next line of code in my @RestController..
These are the changes I did:

```
public class DistanceController {

    private final CurrentLocationService currentLocationService;
    private final ICitiesRepository citiesRepository;
    private final ICountriesRepository countriesRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public DistanceController(CurrentLocationService currentLocationService, ICitiesRepository citiesRepository,
                              ICountriesRepository countriesRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.currentLocationService = currentLocationService;
        this.citiesRepository = citiesRepository;
        this.countriesRepository = countriesRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }
```

This is the "new" error log:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot invoke "me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.repositories.ICountriesRepository.getById(Object)" because "this.countriesRepository" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.repositories.ICountriesRepository.getById(Object)" because "this.countriesRepository" is null
    at me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.controllers.DistanceController.getDistance(DistanceController.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

There is the code of the ICountriesRepository:

```
package me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.repositories;


import me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.entities.CountryEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface ICountriesRepository extends JpaRepository<CountryEntity, String> {

}
```

Also, I am adding the code of a @Configuration I made for the ModelMapper:

```
package me.givo.distancebetweenus.getdistance.config;

import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

}
```

Comment: did you autowired  the CurrentLocationService into DistanceController ?

Comment: Hello, shivam. I didnt, since I was injecting in the controller constructor but I made the try of adding the Autowired as well and now I am getting the same null error this time in the next Repository the Controller uses. I will update the initial question. Thanks.

Comment: The dependency injection happens when you start the application. Are you getting any exception at that point?

Comment: Try to annotate the consturctor with @Autowired. Spring(since 4.3) autowires the ONLY constructor by default, is there a construtor you didn't show us?

Comment: Hello.
Ervin Szilagyi, I am getting no exception when the application starts. I am getting a Jpa WARN alone. Also, is it normal that Intellij is marking my RestController as "Class 'DistanceController' is never used" and suggest to safe delete it?

Turo, I edited my  original question with some changes in my RestController properties and constructor, is that what you are referring?

Thanks!

Comment: Now you've created a mess there, please leave the `@Autowire` just on the constructor.  Please show use this class/interface `ICountriesRepository`.

Comment: Ervin Szilagyi, I change it back so the @Autowired is over the constructor alone. I added the ICountriesRepository code in the original question since it looks ugly here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been a bit busy during week days so wasn't able to review my code until now and I found that the only GetMapping method my controller has it was **private**. I just made it **public** and all run as expected already. Thanks all for your time.